# OCaml Core_unix.fork with Core_unix.exec never returns

Tags: ocaml

I'm having trouble fork execing in the following manner because the child process returns a `Core_kernel.Std.never_returns` and the parent is attempting to return `()`.

I get the error `This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type Core_kernel.Std.never_returns = Core_kernel.Nothing0.t`. Can't seem to find the propper way of doing this with `Core.Std`.

```
open Core.Std
open Unix

let () = 
  let prog = "ls" in
  let args = ["ls"; "-l"] in
  match Unix.fork () with
  | `In_the_child ->
     Unix.exec ~prog:prog ~args:args ();
  | `In_the_parent _ ->
     (* continue on with the program *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `never_returns` type is specially designed to be consumed with `never_returns` function. This is to require a programmer to state clearly in the code, that he understands that the expression doesn't terminate. Here is a working example:

```
let () =
  let prog = "ls" in
  let args = ["ls"; "-l"] in
  match Unix.fork () with
  | `In_the_child ->
    Unix.exec ~prog ~args () |>
    never_returns
  | `In_the_parent _ -> ()
```